# Search engine error?

Tags: php, search

Image of code and phpmyadmin: http://www.dodaj.rs/f/Z/d0/2BO43myA/dwm-2015-04-08-19-27-19-.png

I thing the error is in `$query = $db->query`...

I have two errors:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp32\htdocs\Ceragem\search.php on line 78

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp32\htdocs\Ceragem\search.php on line 82
```

PHP Code

```
    <?php
        require_once 'connect.php';

        if(isset($_GET['qsearch'])){
            $search = $db->escape_string($_GET['qsearch']);

            $query = $db->query("
                SELECT ime, prezime
                FROM data_users
                WHERE body LIKE'%{$search}%'
                OR ime LIKE '%{$search}%'
            ");
            ?>
            <div class="naso_res">
                Nadjeno je <?php echo $query->num_rows;?> // Line 78
            </div>
            <?php

            if($query->num_rows){ // Line 82
                while($r = $query->fetch_object()){
                ?>
                    <div class="rezultati">
                        <a href="#"><?php echo $r->ime;?></a>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: your query is failing. check your column names

Answer (score 0):

Your Query is wrong.

Your table has no `body` attribute

```
 WHERE body LIKE'%{$search}%'
```

Also it shoud be `LIKE '%$search%'` without `{}`

Take a look at this [document](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).